# How to increase QSlider size in QT for Linux?

Tags: qt, resize, slider, qslider

I have a QSlider in Forms.I want a big sized slider, tried increasing slider pointer by stretching the height.But the pointer size remains same.However this is working fine with Windows.I want the same behavior in Linux.
Someone please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with stylesheets: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qslider

Comment: Thanks Miki. That really rocks.